# Why does Excel VBA throw a Class not registered error for an Adobe reference?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, adobe

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to read some text from a pdf.

I read that I need to reference the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. So I downloaded the Acrobat DC SDK for windows from download page and added the reference (through 'Browse'). The code compiles fine, doesn't throw an error during compilation. It recognizes the new acrobat objects. But when I run it, it throws the following error ... Class not registered ... on this line

```
Dim objAVDoc As New AcroAVDoc    ' --- recognizes this object reference fine

If (objAVDoc.Open(strFilename, "")) Then    ' --- throws error here
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I expect the type library is just the 'interface' to be able to access the product programmatically, but you would still need to have an installed product (Acrobat) itself also.

Comment: Did you install 'Adobe Acrobat Pro 10', or 'Adobe Acrobat DC'? What you read can be obtained only if you have one of these versions installed... Theoretically, you should not have the referenced library available. Do you have Acrobat Reader installed?

Comment: The two working versions are not free...

Comment: I have Adobe Acrobat DC installed and decided to download the SDK for that product. I installed he reference for that download and nothing changed. I was able to use a method that opens the file as an object through the shell, and uses, ugh, some Send Keys, some Waits, and a GetFromClipboard. Not the cleanest, but a solution none-the-less.

Comment: Update .. I have Adobe Reader DC installed, and not the same as Acrobat Standard DC, obviously. Probably time to forfeit some coin and stop being stingy.